# Software Load Balancing in C#. Public IP: diverting requests to different servers

Tags: c#, load-balancing

I have to implement a load balancer (software) which will divert requests to different servers using a round robin algorithm.

**Requirements:**
Two machines are configured.

1. Machine has two IPs configured

   - Public IP (x.x.x.10)
   - Server1 (x.x.x.11)
2. Server2 (x.x.x.12).

User will always request `http://x.x.x.10/WebApp/home.html`

Every request/refresh of page in a browser should be allocated to a server in round robin fashion:

```
x.x.x.10/WebApp/home.html    
x.x.x.11/WebApp/home.html
x.x.x.12/WebApp/home.html
x.x.x.10/WebApp/home.html
x.x.x.11/WebApp/home.html
```

As I have to develop in C#, the load balancer should be a library, so in future I can re-use it for other purposes.

As x.x.x.10 is a public IP, shall I have to work on HttpHandler on x.x.x.11 hosted app to divert the call.

Comment: Is this homework? It's pretty rare to need a custom-built load-balancer, and the description is very "academic." Oh, also: what have you tried? What are you stuck on?

Comment: Load balancing between IP addresses only works when one of your IPs doesn't see the request to begin with (meaning it needs to happen before the request hits your NIC). You can load balance app pools or IIS applications but otherwise it defeats the purpose.

Comment: I tried suggest implementation steps in similar question - see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15101680/load-balance-from-scratch/15102271#15102271

Comment: @dlev: This is not a academic project. I need to create a LB program to forward the requests to lookup IPs which i will get in runtime.          M.Babcock: I do agree with your comments. I am trying to find is there any possiblities to access Http.sys,Httplisterner or any other services or process to handle and get the request and using Roundrobin i can divert the requests to lookup.                               Let me know if we can implement it in C#.